# Straight lines and its application

Tags: geometry

I have been working out a problem where we need to find the tangent of the angles between two straight line. I fiqured out that if we had the slopes of the two lines to be of opposite signs we had two different values of the tangent for the two different angles between the straight line. But as soon as we take the values of the slope of the same sign we got the same value of the tangent for the both the angles. So i wanted to figure out if that is neccesary to happen if we take same sign slopes or i am somewhere wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Given the slope of a straight line $y=mx+b$, the angle of inclination is $\tan^{-1}m$.

Now suppose you have two lines $y=m_0x+b_0$ and $y=m_1x+b_1$ and they intersect at some point $P$. You can rotate both lines about some point so that the angle between them is preserved and the first line maps on to the $x$-axis, making its new slope $0$. In order to do this, it will have had to be rotated $\tan^{-1}m_0$ degrees clockwise about the point it was rotated about, and so the second line was as well. The angle of inclination of the image of the second line is the angle between the two, and since they were both rotated $\tan^{-1}m_0$ degrees, the new angle of inclination should be $\tan^{-1}m_1-\tan^{-1}m_0$.

Comment: My question is that without rotating or doimg anything with the pair we have two angles between them ...one acute one obtuse. But when we try to find the tangent of the two angles between them given that the slopes are of same sign we find out that both the values of the tangent of the angles is same.This is where i am having a doubt if it is true or not .and your answer does not seems to answer it

Comment: Oh. In that case, this question seems to be more about the properties of the tangent function then about two lines, since you are trying to prove that $\tan(\tan^{-1}m_1-\tan^{-1}m_0)=\tan(180-\tan^{-1}m_1\tan^{-1}m_0)$ when if $\tan^{-1}m_0$ and $\tan^{-1}m_1$ are both of the same sign.